# Need to change tr color in my php mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have a table where data is fetched from the MYSQLi table, I have a column as 'status' where it has two values of `ACTIVE` and `DEACTIVE`. I need deactive in different bg color/font color and active status in the different color, how could I achieve this through if else statement. At least td is changed also no problem.

```html
 <?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';

// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM retail";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

        echo "<table class='table js-dynamitable table-bordered table-striped table-condensed'>";
            echo "<thead>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th>#</th>";
                    echo "<th>operator_name</th>";
                    echo "<th>zone</th>";
                    echo "<th>nas_ip</th>";
                    echo "<th>switch_name</th>";
                    echo "<th>switch_ip</th>";
                    echo "<th>switch_port</th>";
                    echo "<th>connected_port</th>";
                    echo "<th>vlan</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
            echo "</thead>";
            echo "<tbody>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<tr>";

                    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['operator_name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['zone'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['nas_ip'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['switch_name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['switch_ip'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['switch_port'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['connected_port'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";



                    echo "<td>";


                        echo "<a href='readr.php?id=". $row['id'] ."'  title='View Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a>";
                        echo "<a href='updater.php?id=". $row['id'] ."'  title='Update Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>";
                        echo "<a href='deleter.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModalLong'  title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";

                    echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</tbody>";                            
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I am Using this script too, which is correct format for header

```js
 var $table = $('table');
    $table.bootstrapTable({


      search: true,
      pagination: true,

      buttonsClass: 'primary',



      minimumCountColumns: 2,
      columns: [{
          field: 'id',
          title: 'ID',
          sortable: true,
        }, {
          field: 'operator_name',
          title: 'OPERATOR NAME',
          sortable: true,
        }, {
          field: 'zone',
          title: 'zone',
          sortable: true,
        },
        {
          field: 'nas_ip',
          title: 'nas_ip',
          sortable: true,
        },
        {
          field: 'switch_name',
          title: 'SWITCH NAME',
          sortable: true,
        },
        {
          field: 'switch_ip',
          title: 'SWITCH IP',
          sortable: true,
        },
        {
          field: 'switch_port',
          title: 'SWITCH PORT ',
          sortable: true,
        },
        {
          field: 'connected_port',
          title: 'connected_port',
          sortable: true,
        },
        {
          field: 'vlan',
          title: 'VLAN',
          sortable: true,
        },






        {
          field: 'operation',
          title: 'Action',
        },
      ],

    });
```

Comment: you want to change the color of <td> depending on status type?

Comment: yes correct.exactly

Comment: I recommend at first you learn coding and formatting correctly. Here people has to read and understand your question, and respect them. also, you'd better use 1 echo command and dot, instead of 100s echos. also, correct indents and CSS classes, instead of hardcoding the styles.

Comment: Please use the snippet editor correctly. You can format html, css and JS, but if the snippet is not runnable, just click TIDY and remove the first "begin snippet" line after inserting it. If you want a [mcve], then add HTML instead of PHP. If you just want to past code, please indent 4 spaces and make sure there are no tabs in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're using bootstrab table plugin. You need to add rowStyle handler.

In your JS script you can try add.

```
function rowStyle(row, index) {
  var classes = ['success','danger'];

  if(row.vlan=="ACTIVE")
  return {
     classes: classes[0]
  };

  if(row.vlan=="DEACTIVE")
  return {
     classes: classes[1]
  };

  return {};
}
```

In your PHP file:

**Change:**

```
echo "<table class='table js-dynamitable table-bordered table-striped table-condensed'>";
```

**To:**

```
echo "<table data-row-style='rowStyle' class='table js-dynamitable table-bordered table-striped table-condensed'>";
```

**Change:**

```
echo "<th>vlan</th>";
```

**To:**

```
echo "<th data-field='vlan'>vlan</th>";
```

**Demo:** **http://jsfiddle.net/jyjafk8v/**

http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/ - search 'rowStyle' if you need more info about it.

Comment: when i am reloading ur code works.once reload stops it backs to normal condition without color.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: it's working, but table pagination and search box all gone and all data displaying the whole page. I had set pagination by javascript not works

Comment: Mr.Blue.Thanks for your part.It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed status td (column) . Add inline style and apply background color on if else base. Check the code below.

```
<?php
  // Include config file
  require_once 'config.php';

  // Attempt select query execution
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM retail";
  if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

    echo "<table class='table js-dynamitable table-bordered table-striped table-condensed'>";
        echo "<thead>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>#</th>";
                echo "<th>operator_name</th>";
                echo "<th>zone</th>";
                echo "<th>nas_ip</th>";
                echo "<th>switch_name</th>";
                echo "<th>switch_ip</th>";
                echo "<th>switch_port</th>";
                echo "<th>connected_port</th>";
                echo "<th>vlan</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";

                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['operator_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['zone'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['nas_ip'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['switch_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['switch_ip'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['switch_port'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['connected_port'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td style='color:white;background-color:".($row['status'] == 'ACTIVE'?'green':'grey').";'>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";

                echo "<td>";


                    echo "<a href='readr.php?id=". $row['id'] ."'  title='View Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a>";
                    echo "<a href='updater.php?id=". $row['id'] ."'  title='Update Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>";
                    echo "<a href='deleter.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModalLong'  title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";

                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody>";                            
    echo "</table>";
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} else{
    echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
}
} else{
   echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . 
   mysqli_error($link);
 }

// Close connection
 mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: it's working only page loads, but once the page loaded got finished again came back to normal columns only

Comment: @kavitha just remove table class js-dynamitable